# How can I click first video in youtube with python after searching one?

Tags: python

I got a voice assistant and when I say play on youtube despacito it searches it. However, the problem is how to click on the first video from the list?

Here is the code:

```
if "play on youtube"  in text:
            speak("Which music would you like me to play")
            text = get_audio()
            text= text.split(" ")
            search_5 = str(text[0: ])
            speak("Hold on")
            webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query= " + search_5)
            from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
            from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
            from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
            browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@src, "https://www.youtube.com/embed")]'))
            WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Play"]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I finally did it.

```
        elif "play" in text:
            api_key = "AIzaSyBU0DwkHwP7Iih82aQozxr-UmI-w9Uxcng"
            from apiclient.discovery import build   
            text= text.split("play")
            search_5 = str(text[0: ])
            youtube = build("youtube" , "v3" , developerKey = api_key)
            req = youtube.search().list(q = search_5 ,part="id",type="video",fields="items/id") 
            res = req.execute()
            urlad = res['items'][0]['id']['videoId']    
            webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + urlad)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class "yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" in.click() method.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mixal\Desktop\Diana.py", line 274, in <module>
    browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@src, "https://www.youtube.com/embed")]'))
NameError: name 'browser' is not defined